# Eclipse installation error on mac (incompatible JVM)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have just updated to OS X on my 2009 macbook pro, however when I downloaded Eclipse 64bit I am getting an error message like this: 
Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.7 or greater is required. I am not sure what I need to download to be able to make eclipse open on my computer. If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: you currently have java 1.6.0_65 installed on your machine. You need to check the requirements for eclipse, find which versions of java are suitable, go to the [java download page](https://www.java.com/en/) and download the version you need.

Answer (score 5):

Download and install the [latest JDK from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: Worked for me!  Thanks